# can check in baggage be two pieces

Tags: luggage, qatar-airways

I am flying from Germany to India with Qatar Airways, in economy class. My total baggage should not exceed more than 30 kgs.

My question is, can I break down this 30 kgs allowance into two bags, as long as the total weight doesn't exceed more than 30 kgs?

I checked the website, there's no information given about the number of pieces that can be checked in - it only mentions the total weight up to 30 kgs.